# Push new view controller with web view from table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, rss, push

I am making an app with a tab bar and one of the tabs is an rss reader, the app works, but I can't figure out how to display the selected article content in a UIWebview. everything works right now except upon selecting a cell it pushes to DetailViewController.xib which has a UIWebView in it. But I have it set up so the code finds the URL of the article automatically I just can't figure out how to display it in the UIWebView. Also relatively an Objective-C noob

```
#import "RSSTableViewController.h"
#import "OCVMobileAppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation RSSTableViewController
@synthesize detailView;



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Initialization

/*
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
    // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

/*
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
*/


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        NSString * path = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }
    cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
}

- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL {
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
    // this may be necessary only for the toolchain
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];
    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];
    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [rssParser parse];
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);
    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
        [stories addObject:[item copy]];
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"all done!");
    NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
    [newsTable reloadData];
}
/*
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
*/
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [stories count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    int storyindex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length]-1];
    [cell setText:[[stories objectAtIndex:storyindex]objectForKey:@"title"]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];
    // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"link: %@", storyLink);
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewController animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newviewController animated:YES];
    }

}



/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/


/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
    // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [currentElement release];
    [rssParser release];
    [stories release];
    [item release];
    [currentTitle release];
    [currentDate release];
    [currentSummary release];
    [currentLink release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[newviewcontroller.mywebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]];
```

(replace `mywebview` with your own webview name)

Would this do?

Comment: I made it that and I am getting these errors:
Expected ':' before '.' token and a bailing out confused by earlier errors

Comment: @matthew s - Could you provide an example of when that error occurs?

Comment: NSString *requestURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
  [DetailViewController.rssview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]];

It occurs, well at least the ':' error occurs at the DetailViewController.rssview line, I could add a link to the entire project if that would be more useful?

Comment: Try this. You declared a `DetailViewController` in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Through this: `DetailViewController *newviewController=[[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];`. Try replacing `[DetailViewController.rssview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]];` with `[newviewController.rssview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestURL]]];`. (Whether you provide a link to your project is up to you)

Comment: I tried both and got the same error i56.tinypic.com/334n489.jpg I also added the property line and synthesized it, but still get the error in the picture

Comment: @matthew s - Sorry I overloaded you there. But what fichek below said was what I was trying to tell you. Could you provide a screenshot or something of your latest problem? I'm not quite understanding you.